# eclipse neo4j Java Virtual Machine error

Tags: java, eclipse, neo4j, jvm

I just installed eclipse helios, but I´m not sure about the JDK installation.

I got the error

[image]

In the Properties->Java Build Path I have jre7

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin
```

Which I guess is JRE version 7. But in my command line I got:

[image]

the file *eclipse.ini* is:

[image]

If I run my app I got this:

[image]

Suggestions?
Thank you in advance

Comment: This error indicates that you are trying to execute/use classes compiled for Java 8, which can’t work using a Java 7 installation. Your command line output indicates that you have more than one JVM installed. Note that `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7` does not only indicate a Java 7 installation, but a 32 bit JVM, whereas your Java 9 installation is a 64 bit JVM.

Comment: and what should I do? update JVM to 9?

Comment: You already have a Java 9 installation. You only have to [tell Eclipse about it](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fdebug%2Fref-installed_jres.htm) and then pick that JVM in the [run configuration](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-java-local-configuration.htm?cp=1_3_6_3). It might be that your Eclipse doesn’t recognize the Java 9 installation. Then, you have to do either, install Java 8 or update Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you, in deed I made changes in Eclipse and now is working.